# dynamically changing groupby object in memory without reconstructing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

add new index to grouper pandas.

Say I have a dataframe `df` indexed by `id`.

Suppose I have a collection of other dataframes with one columns, `df1,df2,..dfn`, indexed by `id`.

Given that the commands `keys=[df1,..,dfn]`, and `grouper=df.groupby(keys)` take several seconds to run (because my dataframe is very large).

I would like to add new rows to my dataframe `df`, and part of this process will entail identifying the group this row should be in (i.e. one of: grouper.groups.keys()), and finally, I would like to add this row to the dataframe.

My question is: does pandas.GroupBy offer such functionality?  Do I need to create another mechanism in which to manage the new row additions?  Can you advise on how one would build this aside from constructing my own dict to run in parallel to the `grouper.groups` dict.

In theory, I could just regroup everything each time a new row gets added to the dataframe, but considering the dataframe is on the order of 2MM+, I'd prefer doing this not with every new row.

Comment: this is not possible currently. Do you really need to regroup on a single row? Why don't you just figure out the group then redo that particular computation?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a LOT of groups, several seconds for just the groupings is very odd.

```
In [18]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2000000 entries, 0 to 1999999
Data columns (total 4 columns):
data1    float64
data2    float64
key1     object
key2     object
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 76.3+ MB

In [19]: %timeit df.groupby(['key1','key2'])
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.3 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit df.groupby(['key1','key2']).sum()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.5 s per loop
```

To create

```
N = 2000000
ngroups = 20000

def get_test_data(ngroups=100, n=N):
    unique_groups = range(ngroups)
    arr = np.asarray(np.tile(unique_groups, n / ngroups), dtype=object)

    if len(arr) < n:
        arr = np.asarray(list(arr) + unique_groups[:n - len(arr)],
                         dtype=object)

    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

# aggregate multiple columns
df = DataFrame({'key1' : get_test_data(ngroups=ngroups),
                'key2' : get_test_data(ngroups=ngroups),
                'data1' : np.random.randn(N),
                'data2' : np.random.randn(N)})
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I'll have a read of this in detail over the next few days. For now I do have over 70k groups, and 2MM listings.